# Position tab missing in the Block Theme Editor

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

**Hello,**
Using WordPress 6.2.2 with a custom block theme created from scratch, and I'm trying to make my header sticky. *And what I thought would be an easy task then became a challenge.*
I got to find: [This official WordPress resource](https://learn.wordpress.org/tutorial/adding-a-sticky-header-or-banner/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20sticky%20header%2C%20make%20your%20way,up%20your%20Settings%20and%20scroll%20down%20to%20Position.) explaining how to do that, but they have a position tab I haven't seen. Do I have to activate something in my theme.json? As it not work in CSS too, I think some classes got to cancel the sticky thing.
**Thank you very much for helping me!**

*Images are what they have, VS what I have:*

[image: What they have]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you have the newest WordPress version (WP 6.2.2 at the time of this writing)
2. Check that you are editing *group block*. If you are not, then select from the block menu "group" to wrap a block in a group. Only group block has sticky option.